# Basic question about width versus depth of a first order sentence

Tags: logic

I am reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4865) article on the logical complexity of graphs, and I am having some confusion about the width and depth of a first order sentence $\Phi$, denoted $W(\Phi)$ and $D(\Phi)$ respectively. Intuitively, I would immediately say that these two quantities are equal, but in the article it becomes clear that they are not and I am having some trouble in understanding exactly the difference.

If I understand correctly, the following would be a proper first order sentence:
$$
\Phi:=\exists_x \left(\forall_y ( y\sim x\ \vee\ \forall_x (x\not\sim y)) \right) ,
$$
the above expressing the fact that there is a vertex, to which every vertex but the isolated vertices are connected. Here $D(\Phi) = 3$ and $W(\Phi) = 2$, as the $x$ variable name is reused. Honestly, I am not entirely sure if what I have just said is correct, my current understanding is that we can sort of override the quantification of some variables within the scope of the quantification... This belief is compounded by the fact that later on in the article, we are playing Ehrenfeucht games and when moving pebbles that are already placed, this increases the depth but not the width, signifying that this is like re-quantification of variables.

I wanted to clear this confusion up for myself but I cannot find enough material online to help me understand what really are the formal rules in this case. So if someone could confirm and maybe shed some additional light on what I am saying that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't read the paper, so my comment may be wrong as to their intended use of quantifiers, but the example sentence you give, while it is, strictly speaking, a well-formed formula, it is nonetheless a bit strange in that the inner use of $x$ masks out the outer use of $x$. In standard usage, it is usually the case that variable clashes are to be avoided, so the sentence would become:

$$
\Phi:=\exists_x \left(\forall_y ( y\sim x\ \vee\ \forall_z (z \not\sim y)) \right) ,
$$

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is also what would be my first thought. In this case it would not make sense to define width and depth of a formula as different things though right? In the book descriptive complexity by Immerman page 10 it says `Each quantifier bounds only the free variables within its scope`. So using the interpretation in this book we have that, using my example formula, the $x$ in $\forall_x(x\not\sim y)$ is not free, and thus the outer $\exists_x$ quantifier does nothing to it. I guess this settles it..

Comment: Consider the following formula which is only intended to illustrate the logical width and depth without mapping to a particular domain: $$\forall x(\exists y(P(x,y) \land \exists z(Q(x,z) \land \exists v(R(x,v) \land \exists w(S(x,w)))$$ So in this case, the logical depth is just 2, while the logical width is 5 = $\vert \{x,y,z,v,w\} \vert$.

Comment: @ShyPerson Thanks for the comment! The depth of that formula is also $5$. But we can come up with easy example such that $D(\Phi) < W(\Phi)$ such as $\exists x P(X) \wedge \exists y Q(y)$, my question was more about the reverse inequality. But it is settled I think as per my other comment.